# Fade on scroll effect

Tags: jquery, fade, fadeout

I've added a script I found on here. It works a treat. However, I've come stuck when trying to apply a fade effect to it. At the minute it just cuts out.

```
script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {


        $(window).scroll(function () {
              var height = $('body').height();
              var scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();
              var opacity = 1;


              if(scrollTop > 400) {
                  opacity = 0;
              }

           $('.social').css('opacity', opacity);
        });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: I tied this and it works. Thanks so much guys:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).scroll(function() { 
// The social div 
var $socialDiv = $('.social'); 

//Get scroll position of window 
var windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop(); 

//Slow scroll of social div and fade it out 
$socialDiv.css({ 
'margin-top' : - (windowScroll / 3) + "px", 
'opacity' : 1 - (windowScroll / 550) 
}); 
}); 
</script>​
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or [.fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) for that effect.

Using `.css('opacity', opacity);` will make make your element to disappear abruptly.

Comment: Sorry I'm being a bit dumb, I change it to  $('.social') .animate("slow");

Comment: It's easier to use `.fadeTo()` here. You can use something like `$('.social').fadeTo('slow',opacity);` Also, instead of 'slow' you could use the number of milliseconds it needs to fade. For example, `$('.social').fadeTo(500,opacity);`